# Ethernet not working on Loki, no IP address

Tags: release-loki

Installed Elementary OS at home using Wifi, all is working fine.
But when connecting to Ethernet cable at work, there is no netwerk connection.

The network card is detected, but there is no IP address.
Network-manager is running, dhclient gives error:
Operation not possible due to RF-Kill.

rfkill list all, gives:
3: phy0: Wireless LAN. Both soft/hard-blocked: Yes.

rfkill unblock all, doesn't help.

Since I am not connected I need to use another computer to create this post.

Comment: reinstalled Elementary with only the open source drivers and not the 3 rd party propietary drivers does not change it - still no ethernet only wireless

Comment: needs IEEE 802.1X authentication for DHCP